# git pull-push giving error

Tags: git

Hi i cloned a local repository on another server http://localipaddress/git/project . It created an empty repository. When i tried to **pull** from the repository, it gave me an error

> Your configuration specifies to merge with the ref 'master' from the
>   remote but no such ref was detected.

On **push** i get the following message

> error:Cannot access url "http://localipaddress/git/project" , return code 22 . Fatal
>   git-http-push failed

What could have been wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is resolved. In mycase , it just worked out using the following url while cloning

**http://username:password@localipaddress/git/project** ,
 instead of **http://localipaddress/git/project**.

May be some issue with the way username/pwds are handled by the repsoitory.

also in the **.git/config** file, need to check whether the following details are present

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = http://username:password@localipaddress/git/project 
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*

[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

Comment: In my case, supplying the username was enough, storing the password in not necessary. So the URL gets http://username@localipaddress/git/project and the password will then be demanded later on.